# Having a date take effect at a specific time of day

Tags: excel

I have the below excel formula that I need some help adjusting

```
=MOD(DATE(2015,6,20)-TODAY(),-14)+TODAY()
```

The formula in it's current state works well however what I want now is to modify it to have it kick in at 5:01 PM.

For example the formula will display 5/23/2015 each day until I get to the 6th of June.  From June 6th it will display 6/6/2015 until June 20th (14 days later) and so forth.  What I want however is for the actual date change to occur at 5:01 PM.  So for example on June 6th at 5:01 PM the date change will then take effect.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the time you want to the date and then subtracting by `NOW()` instead of `TODAY()` should work:

```
=MOD((DATE(2015,6,20) + TIME(17,1,0)) - NOW(),-14)+TODAY()
```